# How to find whole distance between two points in a curved line in R?

Tags: r, distance

I have a similar line graph plotted using R plot function (`plot(df)`)

[image]

I want to get distance of the whole line between two points in the graph (e.g., between x(1) and x(3)). How can I do this?

Comment: What's this curve? Is it continuously differentiable?

Comment: What's "df" --- is it a function? Or a set of points?

Comment: Its a set of points and its not a function

Comment: Okay that's covered by my first point below.

Comment: This isn't a question about how to use R. It can stay open here, IMO.

Comment: @gung It's not about how to use R, but it's also not about statistics.

Comment: Since this is the result of `plot(df, ...)`, presumably `df` is an array-like structure with two columns. Thus, according to the Pythagorean Theorem, `sum(sqrt(rowSums(apply(df,2,diff)^2)))` will give *exactly* the length of the graph as drawn.  Distances between points are similarly calculated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If your function is defined over a fine grid of points, you can compute the length of the line segment between each pair of points and add them. Pythagoras is your friend here:

   [image: drawing of arc length of a small segment with the arc-segment as hypotenuse of a triangle]

   To the extent that the points are not close enough together that the function is essentially linear between the points, it will tend to (generally only slightly) underestimate the arc length.

   Note that if your x-values are stored in increasing order, these ẟx and ẟy values can be obtained directly by differencing (in R that's `diff`)
2. If you have a functional form for *y* as a function of *x* you can apply the [integral for the arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) -- i.e. integrate

   ∫ √[1+(dy/dx)²] dx

between *a* and *b*. This is essentially just the calculation in 1 taken to the limit.

3. If both *x* and *y* are parametric functions of another variable (*t*, say) you can simplify the parametric form of the above integral (if we don't forget the Jacobian) to integrating

   ∫ √[(dx/dt)²+(dy/dt)²] dt

   between *a* and *b*

   (Note the direct parallel to 1.)
4. if you don't have a convenient-to-integrate functional form in 2. or 3. you can use [numerical quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Numerical_integration); this can be quite efficient (which can be handy when the derivative function is expensive to evaluate).

Comment: Thanks for the info.. If I read your answer correct then according to your first point is this correct `x=c(1:50)
y=sin(x)
dis<-sqrt((y^2+(lag(y))^2))
sum(dis)`

Comment: It seems I made an error in calculating dis variable `dis<-sqrt(1+diff(y)^2)` as delta x will be 1 and `s=sum(dis)`

Comment: Uh, you realise that sin(x) is *NOT* approximately linear jumping from x=1 to x=2, don't you? (In any case if your function is sin it seems an odd way to evaluate an elliptical integral. There are functions for computing those things). Try `integrate from 0 to 2*pi sqrt(1+cos^2(x))`  at wolfram alpha ... If you only needed it from say 0 to pi/2 or 0 to pi you can work it out from that via symmetry considerations

Comment: Frankly my math skills are very bad.  The above code is just a sample code. what is in your opinion the right way to find the distance of the above problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "the above problem"- which problem; one where you find the arc length of sin(x) between 1 and 50? Is this homework?

Comment: sorry for the late reply when y=sin(x)?

Comment: @Glen_b: your first solution works for very small steps, so he could do it with x=seq(from=1,to=2,by=0.00001) ? This is in fact the transition to solution 2: $\sqrt{\delta x^2 + \delta y^2}=\delta x \sqrt{1+(\delta y / \delta x)^2}$ and for $\delta x \to 0$ the sum becomes an integral (the third solution can also be derived in this style). (this is of course no ''exact maths'' but as Eka says that his/her math skills are not perfect ...), but good answer (+1)

Comment: @fcop indeed, hence my use of the adjective "fine" in reference to the grid of x-values in the opening sentence - to emphasize the need for tiny step size in x; hence also the emphasis on the need for it to be fine enough that the function is effectively linear on that scale. Grids on the order of your suggested grid size should give around about 4 significant figures. (Interesting that I had assumed that the OP was female where you assumed male)

Comment: Use of quadrature (even something as basic as Simpsons rule) could improve the accuracy substantially

Comment: The question does not appear to concern the length of a *function*: it asks about the length of a graph.  Thus, quadrature would seem to be irrelevant.  Of greater import might be the potential need to perform some interpolation among the *data* `df` in case one or both endpoints do not coincide with data points.